# C - adding base64 methods to my file

Tags: c, makefile, base64

I found these libraries: http://svn.opendnssec.org/trunk/OpenDNSSEC/common/ for encoding in c. I want used them but I am not sure how can I add them.

If I add `#include "b64_ntop.c"` I have problem with `#include <config.h>` in b64_ntop.c (no such file or directory). How can I add these modules?

```
My makefile:
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-std=gnu99 -Wall -pedantic

all: rdtclient

rdtclient: b64_ntop.o rdtclient.o 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) b64_ntop.o rdtclient.o -o rdtclient
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Why are you trying to include `*.c` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that particular file, you can remove every header except `<stdlib.h>` (needed for `abort()`), but you would add `<stdint.h>` to get `uint8_t`.

```
#include <config.h>      // Remove

#include <sys/types.h>   // Remove
#include <sys/param.h>   // Remove
#include <sys/socket.h>  // Remove

#include <netinet/in.h>  // Remove
#include <arpa/inet.h>   // Remove

#include <ctype.h>       // Remove
#include <stdio.h>       // Remove
#include <stdlib.h>      // Keep
#include <string.h>      // Remove
#include <stdint.h>      // Add
```

There's no need for the others that I can see, and GCC agrees with me when I tested it.

I'm not sure which header introduced `uint8_t`; most likely, it was `<sys/types.h>`, but the C standard says `<stdint.h>` does that (or `<inttypes.h>` does it).

You should also have a header which declares the function, and that header should be included in this file to ensure that the function declaration and definition agree, and the header should be included in each source file that uses the function.  Obviously, that's one more `#include` line in the source file.

---

In general, if a file uses `<config.h>` (or, more usually, `"config.h"`), then you need to use the configuration tool (usually `autoconf` or `automake`) or the `configure` script that is generated by the tools to create the `config.h` header.  In this file, there was no conditional code affected by the configuration header, so it could be removed.

---

Once you've cleaned up the header list, you can treat the file as you would any other source file in your project.  It would be best to compile it as a separate object file (no special options needed) which is added to the build.  That's what your `makefile` seems to be doing perfectly well.  Occasionally, it is sensible or necessary to include a source file (as opposed to header file) in another source file.  The number of times that is sensible is strictly limited, though.

Answer (score 0):

You should not `#include` a C file. Instead `#include` compat.h and specify the path to the header file in the `CFLAGS` using the `-I` option thus:

```
CFLAGS=-std=gnu99 -Wall -pedantic -Ipath/to/header
```

Comment: I tried with compat.h including but same problem with config.h. What should I add to -I option? Which path? All files from that link I added to folder with my files. So it should be path to config.h? How can I found it?

Comment: @Bibo As per the make files, it looks like config.h.in is missing from the common/ folder. Try removing the `#include <config.h>` from `compat.h` and the other C files and see if they still compile.

Comment: You´ve right it compile but I must still try to use it if it works. But for now thanks :)